# Cache Buster with Multi-components - SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, caching, sapui5, sap-web-ide, sap-basis

I am currently developing an application that is used by multiple people, it includes multi-components from other projects that I have developed. When I make a change and deploy it to the ABAP repository, the changes do not take place unless I manually reset the cache. This is a problem as I don't want the users to reset their cache every time an update takes place throughout its application life-cycle.

The main project does reset it's cache however the multi-components inside of the project do not reset cache every time the application is refreshed. I have provided code below for both the main project and one of the multi-components.

I have changed the SRC to `'/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js'` and `'resources/sap-ui-core.js'`
however, it is giving me a 'component cannot be instantiated' error

MAIN PROJECT - index.html

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.62.0/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"mainproject.mainproject": "./"}'
data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="./"
data-sap-ui-language="en"
</script>
```

MULTI-COMPONENT - index.html

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.62.0/resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js"
data-sap-ui-async="true"
data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="./"
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"custLookup.custLookup": "./"}'>
</script>
```

Thank you in advance!

Sunil.

Comment: Are you running the cache buster jobs on the ABAP system?